# Indicate new line into console input, without pressing enter key?

Tags: java, console, bufferedreader

I have the following problem, I'm working with a BufferedReader to read some lines that enter from console. The thing is that I haven't been able to figure out how to read the last line without pressing enter key.
For example, using the following code

```
public void readEntry(){
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try{    
        boolean first = true;
        while(true)
        {   
            String line = br.readLine();
            if(first)
            {
                System.out.println();
                first = false;
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
}
```

And the following entry

```
line1
line2
line3
```

I get this output

```
line1
line2
```

Is there a way to indicate to the console that there is a third line, without manually pressing enter key?

Thank you!

Comment: No, not with the standard Java console. Please see the duplicate question for more details.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels But, if I want to read the full line and I know that the input ends after line 3? I Can't print something like an enter key?

Comment: No, not with the standard Java console, you can't.